# Force Apache to send 200 instead of 404 in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to force Apache to send 200 OK instead of 404 in .htaccess I don't know is this possible. I have found below text from one post but it doesn't work I don't know why...

From: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument.html

Create a blank file in your main web directory named 404.. can be blank.
Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 200 /404
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

That will change the Apache ErrorDocument to the /404 file. But the Redirect line causes requests for /404 to issue a 200 OK response instead of a 404.

If that doesn't work it is due to rewrites no doubt. So if that's the case add this under those first 2 lines but above any other rewrite lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the requested file doesnt exist
# and if the requested file is not an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^4]* /404 [L,S=4000]
```

Explained in more detail at: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument.html#Automate_ErrorDocument_Triggering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send 200 status instead of usual 404 you can use this rewrite rule:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^404\.html/?$ - [L]

# If the requested file doesnt exist
# and if the requested file is not an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . 404.html [L]
```

Comment: It's not working... I put the same code from above... It still says 404 not found...

Comment: That means you still have `ErrorDocument 404` line. Comment that out and also remove any other rule like `Redirect` or any other rule.

Comment: http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/11/22/some-no-exist-file.htm   There are no other rules in that file not in the above line of directories.

Comment: aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/11/22/some-no-exist-file.htm  it still not working, Should I put some error redirection file for 404 or somthing perhaps it doesn't have where to go and show 404 again.....

Comment: Ok does `/404` an existing file? It has to be an existing file to make it work.

Comment: I create 404.htm file and put it in /404.htm - is it wrong? .htaccess file I put in /11/22 directory path? It doesn't work like this way- I'm I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: ok see updated code and it should be placed in `DocumentRoot` not in `/11/22` directory.

Comment: Anubhava I have question almost similiar to this one for 403 code see the link.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040634/not-showing-403-code-in-status-200-ok-and-some-page

Comment: OK sure let me take a look.