# Not showing 403 code in status (200 OK) and some page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error-handling

Code below works for error code 404 but for 403 code is not working. It doesn't show page 403.html and continu to show code 403 in status instead of 200 OK. Why?

```
Deny from adsl.eunet.rs 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^403\.html/?$ - [L]

# If the requested file doesnt exist
# and if the requested file is not an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . 403.html [L]
```

Comment: Last rewrite will execute for a request that is not a file or directory.. which is same as 404 handling. May I know how is your code generating 403?

Comment: http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/11/22/121proizvodnja.htm

Comment: Deny from adsl.eunet.rs

Comment: ok if you're using `Deny from` then you must use `ErrorDocument 403 /403.html` directive. Can you php code on your website?

Comment: Php is allowed on my webhost but i have no idea how to use it and what to do.

Comment: Can I do it from Cpanel? or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
### Deny from adsl.eunet.rs 

ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =194.247.196.20
RewriteRule !^(404|403)\. - [F]

RewriteRule ^(404|403)\. - [L]

# If the requested file doesnt exist
# and if the requested file is not an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . 404.html [L]
```

Then inside `/403.php` start with this php code:

```
<?php
   http_response_code ( 200 );
   # rest of your html code
?>
```

Comment: Something is wrong...         http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/11/22/121proizvodnja.htm   It also seems in status still sending 403 code and wont rewrite with php file

Comment: Anubhava take a look at this page it contains php related to my web host perhaps there there is problem something not allowed perhaps this is link http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/11/22/phpallow.htm

Comment: This looks fine and normal to me. You didn't answer my question in previous comment.

Comment: If you mean on whole line ErrorDocument 403 /403.php  I remove it and nothing...  - I remove it completly?  comment out it means perhaps just put # befor line?                   http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/11/22/121proizvodnja.htm

Comment: Is `ErrorDocument` line commented now?

Comment: I remove that line if you mean on that.I delete that line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58380/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user3082821).

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html # define the error document

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L] # match anything, F means return 403 Forbidden, L - last
```

You can check out the flags you can set here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule
And more information on changing the error documents here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: It's not working it shows 500 internat server error... Any idea why..?

Comment: Remove the comments and use L instead of END.

Comment: There is problem 403 code do rewrite but it show in status code that is 403 error and I want not to bee seen in status 403 code message I need 200 OK. Can you help with this?

Comment: You want to return 200 instead of 403 for forbidden files?

Comment: Yes - 200 OK insted of 403 for forbidden files.

Comment: There is no good way to override a status code generated by the server (i.e. when using the `Deny from ..` directive. You can use mod_rewrite to generate "deny" access by matching `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` and `%{REMOTE_HOST}`.

Comment: I can not use %{REMOTE_ADDR} and %{REMOTE_HOST} because it requre hostnamelookups double usage I don't have permission to use on shared host. It do IP reverse lookup and it is not allowed from .htaccess to set it up only from direct Apache changes I don't have access.... That is why I use "Deny from" because I can do it from .htaccess and apache is forced to do double reverse lookup...